# Inequality operator(!= equivalent) in swift

Tags: swift

We check String equality in swift using "==".But how to use **!=** (In objective c) equivalent in swift?I want to check str1!=str2.But compiler is suggesting me to delete '!' character.

Comment: str1 != str2  Just keep space between values. Swift has the same operator

Comment: You want `str1 != str2` – having no whitespace confuses the compiler with the postfix force unwrap operator `!`.

Comment: Thanks @Chathuranga Silva,@Hamish

Comment: You can always write: `!(str1==str2)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The not equal to `!=` operator is the same in Swift as in Objective C, because it is a standard C comparison operator

According to the Swift documentation for [Basic Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html):

> Swift supports all standard C comparison operators:
>
> Equal to (a == b)
>
> Not equal to (a != b)

The reason your example doesn't work, is because you must add whitespace:

```
str1!=str2
```

should be

```
str1 != str2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a white spaces  between the str and !=

It should be str1 != str2